# Assign CLI argument to a string variable in Ada

Tags: command-line-arguments, ada

I am having some issues when attempting to assign a command line argument to an ada program to a string variable.

here is my main procedure:

```
with Ada.Command_Line; use Ada.Command_Line;

procedure proc is
    cli_exception : exception;
    filename : String (1..Argument(1)'length);
    usage : String (1..31);
begin
    usage := "Usage: ./proc [filename]";

   if Argument_Count /= 1 then
       raise cli_exception;
   end if;

   for arg in 1..Argument_Count loop
       case arg is
           when 1 =>
               filename := Argument(arg);
           when others =>
               null;
       end case;
   end loop;

   put_line("filename is: " & filename);
exception
    when e: cli_exception =>
        put_line(usage);
end proc;
```

The problem here is in the declarative part of the procedure where the upper bound to the string "filename" is set. If no CLI arguments are given, then Argument(1) will throw an exception before the procedure even begins because there is no argument #1.

The output is:

```
raised CONSTRAINT_ERROR : a-comlin.adb:65 explicit raise
```

Is there any other way of defining the size of that string variable without using an unbounded string, and without picking an arbitrary number (as fully qualified filenames can get quite large)?

-Thanks

Comment: Why rule out Unbounded_String? They're perfectly well-suited for handling variable length strings. And trivial to convert back and forth with regular strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a declare block inside your procedure and initialize `filename` with the argument value:

```
-- ...
if Argument_Count /= 1 then
   raise cli_exception;
end if;

declare
   filename : String := Argument (1);
begin
   -- do what you want with the filename here.
end;
```

By the way, you could do the same with `usage`:

```
usage : String := "Usage: ./proc [filename]";
```

That way, you do not have to count the characters each time you alter the string.

Comment: If you can, use `constant`: `usage : constant String := ...`.